# Are CSS selectors a big performance hit?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a web application with bunch of HTML code. There are some style-attributes that I can't get rid of, but I was wondering if it's worth the cleanness to get rid of class-names and use CSS selectors instead. Do CSS selectors perform slowly?

I'm talking about replacing class-name selectors such as .example with more complex selectors like #example div > div:nth-child(3) > p

Comment: Can you be more specific and give an example?  I mean, when you put class names on an element and reference them from a CSS file, that too is a "selector".  In fact reference only by class is one of the slower things you can do. However, your question really doesn't make much sense without an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [this article](http://ajaxian.com/archives/css-child-selector-performance) to see a graph on this. I don't know how exact this benchmark is, but it seems child selectors are indeed slower, but you're not going to find any visible gains by avoiding child selectors.. this is a micro optimization that has "diminishing returns" written all over it.

Answer (score 1):

The performance hit is tiny.

Comment: That's not always true, especially for IE6, though it completely depends on the particulars of the page and the selector in question.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find an interesting blog post on the argument with examples and tests of CSS selectors performances on most common browsers:

http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/03/10/performance-impact-of-css-selectors/

This is the conclusion of the author:

> Based on these tests I have the
>   following hypothesis: For most web
>   sites, the possible performance gains
>   from optimizing CSS selectors will be
>   small, and are not worth the costs.
>   There are some types of CSS rules and
>   interactions with JavaScript that can
>   make a page noticeably slower. This is
>   where the focus should be.

Answer (score 0):

The browser matches from *right to left*, and any non-specific tags will cause more of a performance hit.*

1–Slower:

```
.foo p
```

2–Faster

```
.foo p.bar
```

What happens is in the first example, the browser matches ALL paragraphs, then narrows it down to those whose ancestor has the `foo` class.

In the second example, the browser matches all elements that have the `bar` class, then matches the subset that are paragraphs, then the subset whose ancestor has the `foo` class.

One would generally expect the initial set of the second example to be smaller than that of the first example.

*Bear in mind that the hit will really only become apparent with poorly-crafted CSS on pages that are very large (megs) and/or have many, many elements (e.g., hundreds of `span`s or `div`s). Small pages with only a few number of elements will not see a real—if any—performance hit, even with poorly-written CSS.